# Checkmarx: Network not available

Tags: checkmarx

I am running a checkmarx scan using the CLI tool. I've been running it from my local machine with Windows installed and it has worked perfectly.
My issue happens whenever I try to run the same exact command from a VM with Windows installed. I receive this error:

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://checkmarx.server.com/cxwebclient//cxwebinterface/cxWSResolver.asmx?WSDL
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1676)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:646)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:338)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188)
        ... 18 more
[2016-12-05 00:18:48,569 FATAL] Server Name is invalid or network is unavailable. Error message: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.`

Comment: Looks like a networking problem, perhaps the VM is not configured properly. From within the VM, can you ping the server? Access the `https://..../cxwebclient/` URL from there?

Comment: Yes, I can ping the server and access the url :(

Comment: Oh wait, it looks like that says you got a [401 status code](https://http.cat/401) in your response? That means "Not Authorized" - are your local machine / checkmarx server in a Windows Domain that your VM is not, and you have the Cx configured for IWA?

Comment: Battling some of the same issues with Checkmarx

Answer (score 0):

Was able to use the server IP address instead to get this one working as it kept failing to identify the server name.

Thanks.